# Licensing information GetPropertyValue in advance installer?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, installation, advanced-installer

I get the error "Error creating window handle" when getting licensing information from Advance Installer http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-get-licenensing-property.html when my c# application is running in trial mode.

However when I register my c# application and run the same code mentioned in above link i don't get any error but also I don't get any value for the properties mentioned in [link](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/licensing-properties.html).

I am really thankful for your kind help.

Comment: Since this is an Advanced Installer specific question I think you will get a more proper assistance if you post your question on their forums.

Comment: They have a staffer who is very active at answering questions here.  That said, their forum response time is very good (they'll likely want a copy of your .aip and a verbose installation log sent to their support e-mail `support@advancedinstaller.com` in any case).